# how to create a onetime expire email link when we send throught sendSignInLinkToMail method in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

i would like to invite the new user in my react application with firebase email method

i have implemeted this method and its working as i expected
user is aslo getting the email message from the firebase when i invited from the react application as a admin account

this my function to send the mail to the new user through sendSignInLinkToEmail method

**ISSUE** : link has not been expired after user used

EXPECTED : link has to be active for the first time not multipe times

even thought i added the  `singleUse: true`, `oneTimeCode: true`, there is not effect with this properties

Function

```
 const sendLoginLink = (email) => {
    const actionCodeSettings = {
      url:
        "http://localhost:3000/auth/sign-up?email=" + encodeURIComponent(email),
      handleCodeInApp: true,
      // Expire the link after first use
      // This is achieved by setting the singleUse and oneTimeCode options to true
      singleUse: true,
      oneTimeCode: true,
      dynamicLinkDomain: "my email",
      // Set the email subject
      // This is optional
      emailSubject: "invitation from my app",
      // Set the email body
      // This is optional
      emailBody: "please click the this link to sign up into the account",
    };

    firebase
      .auth()
      .sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, actionCodeSettings)
      .then(() => {
        // The link was successfully sent
        console.log("link send successfully");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle the error
        console.log(`link send unsuccessfully ${error}`);
      });
  };
```

please i have tried so many ways but its not expiring could anybody tell me
how to do this

any help is so appriciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find in the documentation `singleUse` and `oneTimeCode` params.

Here is the updated example.
First, you need to send a login link. For that dynamicLink setup is required if Firebase. Google will suggest to create a `yourproject.page.link` url. `handleCodeInApp: true` is required also.

```
  const sendLoginLink = (email) => {
    const actionCodeSettings = {
      url:
        "https://localhost:3000/auth/sign-up?email=" +
        encodeURIComponent(email),
      handleCodeInApp: true,
      dynamicLinkDomain: "your.page.link",
      emailSubject: "invitation from my app",
      emailBody: "please click the this link to sign up into the account",
    };

    firebase
      .auth()
      .sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, actionCodeSettings)
      .then(() => {
        // The link was successfully sent
        console.log("link send successfully");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle the error
        console.log(`link send unsuccessfully ${error}`);
      });
  };
```

The next step is to create a page where you will handle the link clicked processing. In the asked case it will be `auth/sign-up` page.

```
  const signedIn = () => {
    const url = window.location.href;      
    if (firebase.auth().isSignInWithEmailLink(url)) {
      console.log("From email link");
      const search = window.location.search;
      const params = new URLSearchParams(search);
      const email = decodeURIComponent(params.get('email') ?? '');

      if (!email) {
        console.error('Email is not passed to URL');
        return;
      }

      firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailLink(email, url)
        .then((result) => {
          // Clear email from storage.
          console.log(result);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
          // Some error occurred, you can inspect the code: error.code
          // Common errors could be invalid email and invalid or expired OTPs.
        });
    }
  };


useEffect(() => { signedIn(); }, []);
```

Now if you click the first time, a user will be signed up successfully.
The second time `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailLink` will raise an exception due the code usage. It is possible to check `error.code` to properly handle the messages. Tested with `firebase@8.10.1`.

[image]

P.S. recommend to update to the new [Modular Firebase NPM package (v >= 9)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade).

Comment: thanks for the response here is my npm version of firebase `"firebase": "^8.10.1",`

Comment: Thank you Yeah that really helped but i stucked in different problem like is there any way to change the email body content , subject , and sender mail address. I have found this can be done with firebase cloud function but it asked me to upgrade project plan when i’m trying to deploy my custom function into the fb cloud. Cant we send mails with body subject and address in free tiar or do we really need fb cloud functions

Comment: And I'm planning to replace sendSignInLinkToMail with normal email including with dynamic onetime expiration link. Reason when i use that method as like you said user sign up directly without password. Client side signup page wont be available I made that with protected routes only when new user comes through the invite link they can see it. Expected : needs to redirect to signup page and proper mail body subject address in mail. Please could you tell me in which way i can achieve this. Regarding mail template I’m not sure does that available in free tiar

Comment: @jsBug You can check whether a user is loged in by looking at `getauth().currentuser` or `fireabase.auth().currentUser`, and protect you page paths. It is possible to update email templates at Firebase -> Authentication -> Templates. HTML code is allowed too, so you are free to change it how you want. Free plan allows to change Templates. Also Spark (non free plan) is affordable - you pay only for what you use.

Comment: @jsBug To send a custom email you need to have a separate service for it, or run a custom email (SMTP) server. Some email services to use, all are non-free: Trigger Email from Firestore extension (add it under Extensions in Firebase), Postmark.com.